# What happens when an item is deleted from a list initialized by hashmap.values()?

Tags: java, android, list, hashmap

I have the following declaration in class A:

```
Map<String, MyClass> myMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, MyClass>());
```

Class A also has this function:

```
public List<MyClass> getMapValuesAsList() {
    return new ArrayList<>(myMap.values());
}
```

In class B, I have a `List` initialized like this:

```
List<MyClass> myList = cart.getMapValuesAsList();
```

What I assume is that `myList` keeps references to the values of `myMap`. When I call a setter function in an item in `myList`, the related value is also updated in `myMap`, supporting my assumption. However, whenever I delete an item from `myList`, `myMap` continues to keep the `MyClass` instance in it. This removed instance is probably not garbage collected since `myMap` still has a reference to it. Am I right?

Is there any automated way to delete key-value pair from map when the value is removed somewhere else?

UPDATE: Class B pass `myList` to an Android adapter. Therefore, I need some kind of `get` functionality. Collection doesn't have such a method. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `List` contains references to the instances that are the values of your `Map`, so mutating the state of individual elements of the `List` mutates values of the `Map`.

On the other hand, your `List` is not backed by the `Map`, so removing elements to it won't affect the entries of the `Map`.

> Is there any automated way to delete key-value pair from map when the value is removed somewhere else?

Yes, if you remove an element directly from the `Collection` returned by `myMap.values()`, it will also remove the corresponding key-value pair from the `Map`.

This is states in the Javadoc of `values()`:

> **Collection java.util.Map.values()**
>
> Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map.The collection is backed by the map, so changes to the map arereflected in the collection, and vice-versa. If the map ismodified while an iteration over the collection is in progress(except through the iterator's own remove operation),the results of the iteration are undefined. **The collection supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map**, via the Iterator.remove, Collection.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations. It does notsupport the add or addAll operations.

Comment: @Mehmed I'm not sure what your code looks like (the passing of the List to the adapter), so I can't answer that.